# LangChain document tagging using documents in ChromaDB

Tags: openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, chromadb

In the LangChain docs I found that it is possible to tag documents following a scheme that outputs JSON. docs: https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/tagging

Now in this example they use textual input, provided by the user, as "Document".

Now my question is: How do I tag documents that are stored in a vectorDB (ChromaDB in my case) using this method? I also need to ask questions to the vectordb in order to get a correct answer in the JSON.

Thanks in advance!

SG

I tried all the basic tutorials that I found in the Langchain docs, Medium etc.